# How to access multiple databases in a SQLite script?

Tags: sqlite, shell, scripting

I have this script in a file "file.txt"

```
.open new_s.sqlite
.open new.sqlite
.open original.sqlite
ATTACH 'new_s.sqlite' as new_s;
ATTACH 'new.sqlite' as new;
```

To execute it, once opened sqlite3 in bash, i write the commands:

```
sqlite> .read file.txt
```

It works well

```
sqlite> .database
main: C:\...path...\db\original.sqlite
new_s: C:\...path...\db\new_s.sqlite
new: C:\...path...\db\new.sqlite
```

Now, if I want to load some sql files and execute them in exclusive way on each database loaded, what is the syntax?

I need something like
sqlite> main < updatedDb_create_tables.sql;

but it does not work. Is possible to do what I want? If yes, what is the syntax?

Comment: Within an SQL script, you preceed the tablename with the schema (i.e. database) name:  Like `SELECT * FROM new_s.mytable`.

Comment: I know. I want to call some sql scripts from this script. Is it possible to address the calls to one database (like USE predicate in MSSQL ? )